# Add class on specific element without affecting other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to figure out how I can add class on a specific element without affecting the other elements. Here is the page I have been working on

http://www.digitalspin.ph/test/federalland/careers/

If I trigger the "Send Resume" button. The contact form will slide in from the left. The problem is that it also affects the other elements.

Here is the code I have been working on.

```
<li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('six columns job-post'); ?> >
    <div class="content">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <form>
            <input type="button" class="contact-btn" value="Send your resume">
        </form>

        <div class="contact-form hide">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque commodo neque augue, in pellentesque ipsum accumsan eget. Integer efficitur turpis vitae convallis elementum.
            </p>
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="188" title="Careers Contact Form"]'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.contact-btn").click(function(){
        $(".contact-form").addClass("animated slideInLeft").removeClass("hide")
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the "it also affects the other elements" please? Excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse to closest li element using `.closest()` selector in clicked handler from clicked elements context `this`. then use `.find()` selector to target the element with class `contact-form`:

```
$("input.contact-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find(".contact-form").addClass("animated slideInLeft").removeClass("hide")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the closet parent with tagname 'li' to whom the button clicked belongs.

Then once the parent is selected get the element inside it with the 'contact-form' class.

Then just add the required class and remove the 'hide' class.

```
$("input.contact-btn").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').find(".contact-form").addClass("animated slideInLeft").removeClass("hide")
    });
```

Comment: The button's parent doesn't contain the `.contact-form` element.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you have more than one element that has `.contact-form` class. I prefer to bind the click event under the form and button container, so will no issues when you re-arrange the elements. Example:

```
jQuery('.category-job-posts').each(function() {
  var $this = this;

  jQuery('.contact-btn', $this).click(function(){
    jQuery('.contact-form', $this).addClass('animated slideInLeft').removeClass('hide');
  });
});
```